# Change http to https

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, ssl, https

I am learning to use the Google Apps Engine. My code part as `JAVA`. In Google Apps Engine I have created one application as `http://sampleown.appspot.com`. How do I change the URL from `http://sampleown.appspot.com` to `https://sampleown.appspot.com` and redirect `http` and to `https`. How do I use SSL to avoid `http` connection. I don't know the concepts of `SSL` and how to use `SSL` to avoid `http` connections.

Give me Any Idea/Sample Code/Guide Me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general

Does Google App Engine support SSL (HTTPS)?

Google App Engine allows you to serve SSL (HTTPS) traffic through your appspot.com domain. Simply add the 'secure' parameter to your app.yaml handler for the URLs through which you wish to support secure traffic. For complete information on how to configure your application for secure traffic, please see the docs on app configuration.

Java documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

Comment: Vivek Thanks. `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> ` This code can be written where (specified which part to web.xml/appengine-web.xml)

Comment: This goes in the deployment descriptor: war/WEB-INF/web.xml.